# Why is my web socket receiving data packets in the wrong order?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, websocket

I have a C# desktop app that sends jpegs to my server at the rate of 10 per second.

Each jpeg has the time stamp as part of its header and is read by my server.

I am experiencing a disorderly arrival on my server.

the majority of the time the jpegs are received by my sever in the order they have been sent by my client.

But, every now and then the order becomes 'jumbled'.

Are TCP packets supposed to be guaranteed to be sent in order or is it subject to delays by the network/internet?

If the order is guaranteed then I will post my code.

Thanks

My Code:

On Client:

```
   class WebSocketClient
{
    static WebSocket websocket = null;
    public static void Start()
    {
        try {
            Console.WriteLine("Started At: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            if (websocket != null)
            {
                websocket.Dispose();
            }
            websocket = new WebSocket("ws://a uri");
            websocket.Opened += new EventHandler(webSocketClient_Opened);
            websocket.Error += websocket_Error;
            websocket.Closed += new EventHandler(webSocketClient_Closed);
            websocket.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(webSocketClient_MessageReceived);
            websocket.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + " DEBUG#8");
        }
    }

    private static bool TimeOutOccured = false;
    private static DateTime stopped;
    public static void Send(byte[] packet)
    {

        try
        {
            if (websocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                if (packet != null)
                {
                    websocket.Send(packet, 0, packet.Length);
                }
                TimeOutOccured = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (TimeOutOccured)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TimeOut At: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    if ((DateTime.Now - stopped).TotalSeconds > 30)
                    {
                        websocket.Opened -= new EventHandler(webSocketClient_Opened);
                        websocket.Error -= websocket_Error;
                        websocket.Closed -= new EventHandler(webSocketClient_Closed);
                        websocket.MessageReceived -= new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(webSocketClient_MessageReceived);
                        Start();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    TimeOutOccured = true;
                    stopped = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + " DEBUG#9");
        }
    }

    static void websocket_Error(object sender, SuperSocket.ClientEngine.ErrorEventArgs ex)
    {
        try {
            Console.WriteLine("Error At: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Shared.AddError("WebSocketClient.websocket_Error", ex.Exception);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.ToString() + " DEBUG#10");
        }
    }
    protected static void webSocketClient_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            var m_CurrentMessage = e.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + " DEBUG#11");
        }

    }
    protected static void webSocketClient_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Closed At: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            if (websocket.State == WebSocketState.Closed)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + " DEBUG#12");
        }
    }
    protected static void webSocketClient_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Opened At: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

My Server Code:

```
 public void Start2()
    {
        try
        {
            var server = new WebSocketServer("my wan uri");

            ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(FleckLog));

            FleckLog.LogAction = (level, message, ex) =>
            {
                switch (level)
                {
                    case LogLevel.Debug:
                        //gger.Debug(message, ex);
                        break;
                    case LogLevel.Error:
                        SocketMessage("3", message, ex);
                        break;
                    case LogLevel.Warn:
                        SocketMessage("4", message, ex);
                        break;
                    default:
                        SocketMessage("5", message, ex);
                        break;
                }
            };

            server.Start(socket =>
            {
                socket.OnOpen = () => evStatusChanged("Open!");
                socket.OnClose = () => evStatusChanged("Close!");
                socket.OnError = error =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG:1 " + error.ToString());
                    };
                socket.OnBinary = packetIn =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                          //i check my timestamps in my headers here
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + " ServerWebSocket.WebSocketServer_NewDataReceived.Catch3");
                        }
                    };
                socket.OnMessage = message =>
                {

                };
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + " ServerWebSocket.Start2");
        }
    }
```

I am using the WebSocket4Net for my client socket framework

Comment: Order is guaranteed for TCP socket streams. Please post your code.

Comment: @sstan Not going to be a duplicate once he posts his code.

Comment: @sstan absolutely right, I have now re-phrased my question :)

Comment: I will add my serve code now

Comment: You also need to identify the provider of your `WebSocket` class...

Comment: I suspect the issue is the MessageReceived event. We will have to check the docs but the events may not be firing in order, or if multiple event handler thread are being created, they may not run in the order the events were fired.

Comment: @people is this question of mine messy?  Am I being clear?  thanks

Comment: @user957902 yes, that would make sense.  I used Fleck because it was recommended by an article in CodeProject.  the only way to validate this is to compare it to another framework. I am open to suggestions :)

Comment: You should edit the title to make clear that this is about websockets and not about TCP. Your code does not do any TCP work at all.

Comment: @usr thanks for that. I have now done so